# Match and replace whole words in javascript

Tags: javascript, match

I have a textarea, and when I write, for example, "want", I want to replace it with "two".

How can I match and replace whole words in javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the word boundary `\b`, so `\bwant\b`. Do keep in mind that the regex definition of a word may not suit you, though. Javascript regex defines word boundaries as the place between a word character `\w`, which is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and a non-word character (everything except that).

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

---

#### Examples of word boundary caveats

- There's a `\bcan\b` in `"can't"` (because `'` is not a `\w`)
- There's no `\blove\b` in `"love_me"`(because `e` and `_` are both `\w`)

Comment: `\blove\b\w` will never match, because `e\b\w` will never match, because there's no `\b` between `e` and `\w`, which are both `\w`.