# Replace only whole word in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Match and replace whole words in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080037/match-and-replace-whole-words-in-javascript)

I want to replace in JavaScript the word "microsoft" with "stackoverflow".

But I only want it to replace the whole word - so I don't want "microsoft microsftttt" to be turned into "stackoverflow stackoverflowttt".

Comment: See this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080037/match-and-replace-whole-words-in-javascript

Comment: aha...mhm...that sounds like a very strange bug...can you show us some code?

Answer (score -3):

You can add `' '` to begin of string & end of string, replace `' microsoft '` to `' stackoverflow '` and cut `' '` , added before it

Comment: This wouldn't work with other kinds of whitespace, punctuation, etc.