# Replace whole words only using Regex

Tags: javascript, replace

I am trying to replace some letters in a textarea with some text from an input box.
The problem that I am facing is that it replaces all the values that are specified in `CN`.
For example, if `CN` is "A", then "A" will be replaced as well as "A" in "Apple". I want to replace only "A". I have tried using `chordName = CN + " "`, but that replaces values only where `CN` is in the middle of a sentence, not at the beginning of a line.

This is my code:

```
function doit(CN, SC) {
  var rawLyrics = document.getElementById("ttbox").value;
  var chordName = CN;
  var spnCode = SC;
  var res = rawLyrics.replace(new RegExp(chordName, 'g'), spnCode);
  results.innerText = res;
}
```

I also have the problem where "results" textarea gets refreshed with the replaced words rather than changing only the required words i.e, I am using the above code to replace different words in a single block of text, so once I replace one word, and move on to the next, the previously replaced word comes back to it's previous state.

What am I doing wrong? Any solutions?

Comment: Try `\b` around your search term.

Comment: Please ask one question per post. If you have two problems, post two separate questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080037/match-and-replace-whole-words-in-javascript